# Intuition for first Stiefel-Whitney class

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Hatcher's Vector Bundles and K-theory the following description of orientability of a vector bundle $E \mapsto B$ is given:

> For a vector bundle $E\mapsto B$ with
>   $B$ path-connected, orientability is detected by the homomorphism $
> \pi_1(B) \mapsto \mathbb{Z}_2$
>   that
>   assigns 0 or 1 to each loop according to whether orientations of fibers are preserved
>   or reversed as one goes around the loop. Since $\mathbb{Z}_2$
>   is abelian, this homomorphism
>   factors through the abelianization $H_1
> (B)$ of $\pi_1
> (B)$, and homomorphisms $H_1
> (B)→\mathbb{Z}_2$
>   are identifiable with elements of $H^
> 1
> (B; \mathbb{Z}_2
> ).$ Thus we have an element of $H
> ^1
> (B; \mathbb{Z}_2
> )$
>   associated to $E$ which is zero exactly when $E$ is orientable. This is exactly the first
>   Stiefel-Whitney class $\omega_1
> (E).$

Where is the association of element of $H^1(B; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ to $E$ coming from?

I think I'll be able to see that this element is zero if $E$ is trivial if I understood what this association is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Ext}{\operatorname{Ext}}\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$In general, the [Universal Coefficient Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem) tells you that

$$H^n(B;R)\cong \Ext_R^1(H_{n-1}(B;R),G)\oplus \Hom_R(H_n(B;R),G)$$

for a ring $R$ and an $R$-module $G$. In the case $R=\Bbb Z$ and $G=\Bbb Z_2$, some simple homological algebra tells you that $\Ext_{\Bbb Z}^1(H_0(B;\Bbb Z),\Bbb Z_2)=0$, so you're left with $H^1(B;\Bbb Z_2)\cong \Hom(H_1(B;\Bbb Z),\Bbb Z_2)$.

Comment: Awesome username! Anyway, I got the part about the UCT, but what is the association with the vector bundle $E$?

Comment: @Janziek haha thanks! Well the reason they're related to $E$, although $E$ isn't explicitly mentioned much in the construction, is because of the way that the original homomorphism $\pi_1(B)\to\Bbb Z_2$ is defined: the definition is dependent on the way the orientations of the fibers (i.e. subsets of $E$) change as you traverse a loop. If $E$ is orientable, then the orientation is always preserved as you traverse a loop, which corresponds to the map $\pi_1(B)\to\Bbb Z_2$ being zero, which happens iff the associated map $H_1(B)\to\Bbb Z_2$ is zero, iff the first Stiefel-Whitney class is zero.

Comment: @Janziek also I think I should add, once you read (if you haven't already) the construction of *all* Stiefel-Whitney classes, it will be more clear why they depend on $E$. It has to do with using Leray-Hirsch to show that $H^*(E;\Bbb Z_2)$ is a free $H^*(B;\Bbb Z_2)$-module, and extracting unique elements of $H^*(B;\Bbb Z_2)$ by writing some element of $H^*(E;\Bbb Z_2)$ as a unique combination of basis elements.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks Sheaf Keef!